# Script optimization: returning non-indicies digits as strings (Python)

Tags: python, json, list, nested

I am working on a script which reads a json file as a dictionary, finds the nested path of a specific key/value pair, based on the content of the value, and then returns the nested path as a list which I then use later on in the scripts (not important for this question). The nested paths have a mix of indices and string due to the mix of dicts and lists in the json file. I have used the following to traverse the json file and give me the output I need.

```
def traverse(path, obj, output_list):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for i, subnode in enumerate(obj):
            traverse(path + f'{i!r},', subnode, output_list)
        
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            traverse(path + f'{k!r},', v, output_list)  
    else:
        if obj != "":
            output_list.append([int(e) if e.isdigit() else e for e in path])
```

I am now facing a problem, that some of my keys are strict digits due to its nature as ID numbers, meaning that the following isn't a suitable solution

```
int(e) if e.isdigit() else e for e in path
```

as the required output ('415' being an ID number / string)

```
['Materials', 0, 'SurfaceMaterials', 0, '415', 'Name']
```

becomes

```
['Materials', 0, 'SurfaceMaterials', 0, 415, 'Name']
```

So far I have solved this by inserting an additional condition, based on the number of the digit, but this isn´t really the best way to go about it as the index might succeed the limit (99) and the ID might be below the limit(99)

```
output_list.append([int(e) if e.isdigit() and int(e) < 99 else e for e in path])
```

Any suggestion for what I might do instead?

Snippet of Json file:

```
{
"Materials": [
    {
        "SurfaceMaterials": [
            {
                "415": {
                    "Name": "415",
                    "Roughness": 0,
                    "Thickness": 0.2,
                    "Conductivity": 1.3,
                    "Density": 1800.0,
                    "Specific_Heat": 0.84,
                    "Thermal_Absorptance": 0.0,
                    "Solar_Absorptance": 0.0,
                    "Visible_Absorptance": 0.0
                }}]}]}
```

Comment: Hi, your input is missing

Comment: Hi, just added the snippet from the example :-)

Comment: Is path a string or a list?

Comment: Path is a string